# Recursive method in JSP hangs tomcat

Tags: apache, jsp, tomcat, recursion, hashmap

I have a recursive function defined inside my JSP-

```
<%!
public void displayFiles(HashMap files, JspWriter writer) throws IOException {

    Iterator iterator;
    iterator = files.entrySet().iterator();

    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry mEntry = (Map.Entry) iterator.next();
        if(mEntry.getValue() == null) {
            writer.println("<a href=\"DownloadServlet?action=downloadfile&file=" + mEntry.getKey() + "\">" + mEntry.getKey() + "</a>");
            writer.println("<br>");
        }
    }

    iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry mEntry = (Map.Entry) iterator.next();
        if(mEntry.getValue() != null) {
            if(((HashMap) mEntry.getValue()).size() != 0) {
                writer.println("---------------------------");
                writer.println("<br>");
                writer.println("Directory : " + mEntry.getKey());
                writer.println("<br>");
                writer.println("---------------------------");
                writer.println("<br>");
                displayFiles((HashMap) mEntry.getValue(), writer); // recursive call
            }
        }
    }
}
%>
```

Its role is to print out the directory structure which is contained in a HashMap-

```
<%
    map = (HashMap) request.getAttribute("hashmap");
    displayFiles(map, out);
%>
```

**Error**

```
org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket processConnection 
WARNING: processCallbacks status 2
```

I think the reason is -

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomcat-users/200905.mbox/%3C6B028542C4A77D4CB7F06CCC1C1AEB1D018BC5CEE0@AUSP01VMBX03.collaborationhost.net%3E

So how do I go about printing my HashMap recursively to the user ? Structure of my HashMap -

```
Key    |    Value
-----------------
File   |    Null
File   |    Null
Dir    |    Nested HashMap ----> Key   |    Value
File   |    Null                 ----------------
Dir    |    Nested HashMap       File  |    Null
                                 Dir   |    Nested HashMap
```

I hope the structure is clear. JSP receives this HashMap from controller servlet.

Comment: don't use scriptlets, use jstl tags and perform business logic server side

Comment: @NimChimpsky All of my business logic happens server side, I guess what I'm trying to accomplish above is more of View rather than business logic(Model) ?

Comment: This code should be in a Java source files, and use generic collections. Not in a JSP. If it was in a Java source file, you could easily debug it, and create a unit test for it.